# How to use nuget with Visual Studio for phpproj type project

Tags: php, visual-studio, nuget, phalanger

I have installed VS.php and Phalanger for developing a PHP project in Visual Studio.

I am able to debug the PHP project successfully, now I am looking for to add 'bootstrap' as a package  through nuget.

By using "Manage NuGet Packages for solution" option, when I choose to install 'bootstrap' package, the VS show following mesasge.

**'bootstrap' could not be installed because it is not compatible with any project in the solution. The package doesn't target any framework.**

Its a phpproj; PHP project created from VS.php extension, how can i use nuget with phpproj type project.

Answer (score 0):

VS.php is only PHP extension, nothing to do with Phalanger.

Phalanger comes with Phalanger Tools for Visual Studio (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/419916fb-ec89-4f18-ba97-75cf66037797). It cannot co-exist with VS.php since both provide PHP Editor functionality.

Then, if you create new Phalanger Web Project, it should allow you such features as NuGet.

Comment: I am using Phalanger as PHP compiler. I am not using PHP tools because Vs.PHP and PHP tools conflicts, as they both target the same configuration/setting. My question is about adding nuget to phpproj of Vs.PHP, the Phalanger is mentioned to complete info about my environment, i m not saying this is due to Phalanger because I m aware its a compiler and its role will come at the time of compile. The issues seems to be with Visual Studio and Vs.PHP integration.

Comment: VS.Php integration uses deprecated format of phpproj files (not msbuild) and does not support such features. You may contact jcx soft. to implement such features. Phalanger Tools (and PHP Tools) are built on top of MSBuild and supports this extensibility naturally.